# Searching and counting in two-dimensional array

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I have a 2D array, I want to search for identical number in the array and count them. This is what I read from a text file:

```
{001,1,5,6,21},{001,1,5,6,21},(001,1,10,12,18},{002,1,9,10,12},{002,1,6,19,21},{002,1,6,19,21},{001,2,5,6,21},{001,2,6,19,21},{001,2,6,19,21},{002,2,5,6,21},{002,2,6,19,21},{002,2,11,19,21}
```

001 and 002 represent Town,1 and 2 represent Day and the values from 1 to 23
for Town 001, day 1, i Want the program to count the number of occurrence for each value eg.

```
Town day 5 6 9 10 11 12 19 21
001, 1 , 2,2,0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2
002, 1 , 0,2,1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2
001, 2 , 1,3,0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3
002, 2,  1,2,0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 3
```

The array is `TwoDeearray(4,23)`.
This is the code I try to do the counting

```
Dim ArrayCount As New List(Of Integer)
            Dim x As Integer, y As Integer
            For x = 0 To TwoDeeArray.GetUpperBound(0)
                For y = 0 To TwoDeeArray.Rank - 1
                    If TwoDeeArray(x, y) >= ArrayCount.Count Then
                        Do While TwoDeeArray(x, y) >= ArrayCount.Count
                            ArrayCount.Add(0)

                        Loop
                    End If
                    ArrayCount(TwoDeeArray(x, y)) += 1
                Next
            Next
```

Comment: Can you give us the expected output based on the provided input? For example, is 1 counted 12 times or 10 times or {2, 3, 1, 2}. It could be easier if you would store the data in a proper container like a class with good property name.

Answer (score 0):

I don't follow what you are trying to do within the loop but this is how to iterate through your 2D array

```
   Dim twodeeArray(23, 4) As Integer
   For row As Integer = 0 To twodeeArray.GetLength(0) - 1
      For col As Integer = 0 To twodeeArray.GetLength(1) - 1
         If twodeeArray(row, col) > 0 Then  'Change to your test
             ' Your code here
         End If
       Next
     Next
```

You were using TwoDeeArray.Rank, which only shows the number of dimensions.  You also appear to be declaring your array with the bounds reversed.

Hope that puts you on the right track.  If you can explain what you are trying to achieve within the loop, I'll see if I can help there too.

EDIT - responding to comment

This code will loop through your array and give you a list of 'Totals'. Each Total is indexed by Town, Day and Number and contains the count of each.  You just need to run through that list and process it as you need.  Here's the full code:

```
Private Class Totals
    Private _town As Integer
    Private _day As Integer
    Private _num As Integer
    Private _count As Integer

    Public Sub New(town As Integer, day As Integer, num As Integer)
        _town = town
        _day = day
        _num = num
        _count = 1
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Town As Integer
        Get
            Return _town
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Day As Integer
        Get
            Return _day
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Num As Integer
        Get
            Return _num
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Property Count As Integer
        Get
            Return _count
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            _count = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Function MatchFound(town As Integer, day As Integer, num As Integer) As Boolean
        Return town = _town AndAlso day = _day AndAlso num = _num
    End Function

End Class

Private Sub Test()
    Dim twodeeArray(,) As Integer = {{1, 1, 5, 6, 21}, {1, 1, 5, 6, 21}, {1, 1, 10, 12, 18}, {2, 1, 9, 10, 12}, {2, 1, 6, 19, 21}, {2, 1, 6, 19, 21}, {1, 2, 5, 6, 21}, {1, 2, 6, 19, 21}, {1, 2, 6, 19, 21}, {2, 2, 5, 6, 21}, {2, 2, 6, 19, 21}, {2, 2, 11, 19, 21}}
    Dim TotalList As New List(Of Totals)
    For row As Integer = 0 To twodeeArray.GetLength(0) - 1
        Dim town As Integer = twodeeArray(row, 0)
        Dim day As Integer = twodeeArray(row, 1)
        For col As Integer = 2 To twodeeArray.GetLength(1) - 1
            Dim Matched As Boolean = False
            Dim i As Integer = 0
            While Not Matched And i < TotalList.Count - 1

                If TotalList(i).MatchFound(town, day, twodeeArray(row, col)) Then
                    TotalList(i).Count += 1
                    Matched = True
                End If
                i += 1
            End While
            If Not Matched Then TotalList.Add(New Totals(town, day, twodeeArray(row, col)))
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: i want to count the number of occurrence for each number in each Town and day

Comment: I've extended the code to use a Totals class for the counts.  See edited answer above.

Comment: @Networking01 great. Any chance you could mark it as the answer then, please?